how to fetch real-time nested comments with socket.io using express.js and react
I am working on a social media project that allows users to add posts like comments and like comments. my comments array is nested with my array of post objects.
I have successfully implemented socket.io on my post and post like. However, I am finding it challenging to implement it for comments
here is the socket.io set for my server
// Create HTTP server
const server = http.createServer(app);

// Create socket.io server instance
const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: CorsOption.origin, // Allow same origin connections for sockets
  },
});

const startServer = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL);

    server.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Server up and running on port ${PORT}`);
    });
    console.log("Connected to mongodb!");

    // Handle socket connections
    io.on("connection", (socket) => {
      console.log("New socket connected!");

      // Handle socket events for new posts
      socket.on("newPost", (newPostData) => {
        console.log("New post created:", newPostData);
        // Broadcast the new post to all users who are following the user that created the post
        io.emit("newPost", newPostData); 
      });

      // Handle socket events for comments
      socket.on("commentOnPost", (postId, commentData) => {
        console.log("Comment posted on post:", postId, commentData);
    
          io.to(postId).emit("newComment", { postId, comment: commentData });
      });
 

      // Handle disconnections
      socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        console.log("User disconnected");
      });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

startServer();

and for my frontend
const useHandleAddComment = (Comment, postId, setIsLoading) => {

  const { currentUser } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);

  const { posts } = useSelector((state) => state.post);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { socket, listenToEvent, stopListeningToEvent, initialized } =
    useSocketContext();

  const currentPost = posts.find((post) => post._id === postId);

  const comments = currentPost?.Comments || [];

  console.log("comments in use add comment", comments);

  // Handle adding a comment
  const handleComment = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (Comment.current.value.trim() !== "") {
      setIsLoading(true);

      try {
        // Form data for the new comment
        const form = {
          userId: currentUser?._id,
          username: currentUser?.username,
          // profilePicture: currentUser?.profilePicture,
          comments: Comment.current.value.trim(),
        };
        const response = await axios.post(
          `/api/posts/${postId}/comments`,
          form
        );
        const newComment = response.data;
        dispatch(
          setPostcomments({
            post_id: postId,
            comments: [newComment, ...comments],
          })
        );
        // Emit the new comment via Socket.IO
        if (initialized) {
          socket.emit("commentOnPost", postId, newComment);
        }
        Comment.current.value = "";
      } catch (error) {
        alert("Failed to add comment: " + error.message);
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    }
  };

  console.log("comments:", comments);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!initialized || !postId) return;
    // Handle new comments received via socket
    const handleNewComment = ({ postId: receivedPostId, comment }) => {
      if (receivedPostId === postId) {
        const updatedComments = [comment, ...comments];
        dispatch(
          setPostcomments({
            post_id: postId,
            comments: updatedComments,
          })
        );
      }
    };
    // Listen to the "newComment" event
    listenToEvent("newComment", handleNewComment);
    // Clean up listener when the component unmounts or dependencies change
    return () => {
      stopListeningToEvent("newComment", handleNewComment);
    };
  }, [
    initialized,
    postId,
    comments,
    listenToEvent,
    stopListeningToEvent,
    dispatch,
  ]);
  return { handleComment };
};

export default useHandleAddComment;

I see on my server that the socket captures it but my setPostComments doesn't get on the receiver's end.

There are 2 major issues with the current implementation. First is the users not joining post-specific rooms. All users receive the newComment event, but only those viewing the post should get it.
// Server-side: broadcasting to all users instead of room-specific
io.emit("newComment", { postId, comment: commentData });

Other one is the stale comments array. React state might be outdated when updating with new comments.
// Client-side: Directly using stale `comments` array inside useEffect
const updatedComments = [comment, ...comments];

To fix these issues, you must fix it at both the client as well as the server side.
Server Side: Join and broadcast to post-specific rooms.
// Join a room for the specific post
socket.on("joinPost", (postId) => {
  socket.join(postId);
});

// Broadcast comment to the specific post room
io.to(postId).emit("newComment", { postId, comment: commentData });

Client Side: Join rooms and update comments using the latest state.
// Join the room when viewing a post
useEffect(() => {
  if (initialized && postId) {
    socket.emit("joinPost", postId);
  }
}, [initialized, postId]);

// Update state using function form to avoid stale data
const handleNewComment = ({ postId: receivedPostId, comment }) => {
  if (receivedPostId === postId) {
    dispatch(setPostcomments((prevState) => ({
      post_id: postId,
      comments: [comment, ...prevState.posts.find(post => post._id === postId).Comments],
    })));
  }
};


thanks a lot. I tried it but i am it didn't work. also notice you removed listeningToEvent and stopListeningToEvent. If you don't mind clearifying that. Lastly, io.to(postId).emit("newComment", { postId, comment: commentData }); throws an error if its not in a socket.on function
